# .htaccess redirect that remove certain strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I've a framework that load index.php from any of this:

```
website.com
website.com/index
website.com/index/
website.com/index/index
website.com/index/other
website.com/index/some/page/that/not/exists
```

Because controller "index" exists and if it don't find any function, load index.
The same with other subpages:

```
website.com/realpage/
website.com/realpage/index
website.com/realpage/index/some/page/that/not/exists
```

So, it's possible with .htaccess to check if the url contain any "/index" or "index" and remove all content after it?
I need also to force no trailing slash at the end of url.

Result I want:

```
website.com/index                           -> website.com
website.com/index/                          -> website.com
website.com/index/index                     -> website.com
website.com/index/other                     -> website.com
website.com/index/some/page/that/not/exists -> website.com

website.com/realpage/                                -> website.com/realpage
website.com/realpage/index                           -> website.com/realpage
website.com/realpage/index/some/page/that/not/exists -> website.com/realpage
```

Thank you!

@Rafael Saraiva
I've tried with this:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index$ $1 [L]

It show me now 404 on:

```
website.com/index/index
website.com/index/other
website.com/index/some/page/that/not/exists
```

Correct, these page doesn't exists. But still show homepage with this:

```
website.com/index
website.com/index/
```

I would like a redirect here to "website.com".

Answer (score 0):

Excluding specific syntax a general purpose regular expression for that would be:

`(.*)index` or `(.*)\/index`

To test regex use [this site.](https://regex101.com/) To further detect if its a valid url you would need a different regex.

Comment: I've tried with this:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index$ $1 [L]

It show me now 404 on:

    website.com/index/index
    website.com/index/other
    website.com/index/some/page/that/not/exists

Correct, these page doesn't exists. But still show homepage with this:

    website.com/index
    website.com/index/

I would like a redirect here to "website.com".